# Use same column of model in same Query on Waterline ORM

Tags: sql, orm, sails.js, waterline

I've this structure of my tables.

```
Ride
-------------------------------------------
| ID | requestedAt   | requested_for_time |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1556641200000 | 20                 |
| 2  | 1556641200000 | 25                 |
-------------------------------------------

ride_car
------------------------------
| ID | ride_id   | status    |
------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | assigned  |
| 2  | 1         | cancelled |
| 3  | 1         | completed |
| 4  | 2         | assigned  |
| 5  | 2         | cancelled |
| 6  | 2         | completed |
------------------------------
```

Here is the `SQL` query

```
SELECT * 
FROM rides r, ride_cars rc 
WHERE
    r.id = rc.`ride_id` and
    (
    r.requested_at + (r.requested_for_time * 60 * 1000) + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000) 
    ) / 1000 <= CURDATE();
```

This query is worked very fine, The same thing I want in WaterLine ORM but didn't find any way to do the same.
I've tried the code below.

```
const now  = new Date().getTime();
const ride = await Ride.find({
  rideStatus: {'!': ['completed', 'cancelled']},
  requestedAt: {'<=':  (requestedAt + (requestedForTime * 60 * 1000) + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 )) - now}
});
```

And got error that `requestedAt` is not defined. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: We are not there to write code for you. Please add what you tried and recenter your question on which part of the query you can't achieve.

Comment: @TheWildHealer Please check the code I've added.

Comment: A wild guess. I see 'r.requested_at' in the SQL query. Should you be using 'requested_at' instead of 'requestedAt' in your code?

Comment: It's defined in ORM model that in mysql it is `requested_at` and In ORM it is `requestedAt`. There is no concern with that.